# Specflow TestGenerationError

Tags: c#, specflow

I'm trying to understand specflow a bit and I'm following this simple tutorial

> http://specflow.org/getting-started/

Problem is I get this error when I'm trying to execute my first test:

> 1>Calculator.feature.cs(1,8,1,66): error CS1029: #error:
>   'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Interfaces.TestGenerationError'

I have installed SpecRun.SpecFlow and followed tutorial line by line.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know what to add to the original question.I just did the 4 simple steps you see in the tutorial: i) Create unit test project ii) Add SpecRun.SpecFlow iii) Add specflow.feature file with the example scenario of the calculator. iv) Generate step definitions.After these steps I got the error when tried to execute the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error is in the feature.cs file, which is auto-generated.  I can't say what caused the problem with the auto generation initially, but when I ran into this issue, I solved it with the following steps:

1. Copy the text from your .feature file somewhere else.
2. Delete the .feature file from your project.
3. Add a new .feature file
4. Copy your original text back into the new .feature file
5. Re-build your project

This cleared up my issue.  I hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, trying to go through the same tutorial. For me, it was a conflict of Unit Testing packages. I found this by running Build on my project and viewing the errors. There are so many different ones for SpecFlow, it was difficult for me to figure out which ones I needed.

To fix my issue, I deleted my solution and created a new solution and project. 
I am using NUnit with SpecFlow, so I installed NUnit, SpecFlow and SpecFlow.NUnit

Depending on which unit test framework you are using, you will get different code generated to your feature.cs file, but you can only use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Uninstalled SpecFlow.Plus.Excel.2-2-0 and installed SpecFlow.Plus.Excel(Without version in name). This added SpecFLow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation package.